# Extract string with javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

need to extract the string from this ["IBM"], have to get IBM, I have tried like this

```
(/['"]/g,'') way.
var extractor=(/['"]/g,'');
       var newArr = extractor.exec(NAME);

               alert(newArr);
```

Answer (score 4):

You should parse that as JSON:

```
var array = JSON.parse(input);
alert(array[0]);
```

Answer (score 1):

This should get you an array of all the matches

```
var matches = mystring.match(/\[\"(.*?)\"\]/g);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
//variable contains ["IBM"]
variable = variable.substr(2,3);
```

This will work only if the text between the [""] length is 3

Comment: Lol, i admit it's a little bit lazy :)